# For Loop in Python to move through each file sequentially and append it into an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have a directory that has 72 folders, and within each folder are 245 numpy files. The directory is called MP_Data. I would like to read all the 245 numpy files within each folder in any order. However, the loop through the folders should be in numerical order.

The 72 folders are named as follows: (And I would like to keep it that way)

```
r0
r5
r10
r15
r20
r25
r30
r35
r40
r45
r50
r55
r60
r65
r70
r75
r80
r85
r90
r95
r100
r105
r110
r115
r120
r125
r130
r135
r140
r145
r150
r155
r160
r165
r170
r175
r180
r185
r190
r195
r200
r205
r210
r215
r220
r225
r230
r235
r240
r245
r250
r255
r260
r265
r270
r275
r280
r285
r290
r295
r300
r305
r310
r315
r320
r325
r330
r335
r340
r345
r350
r355
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but doesnt seem to work

```
sequences, labels = [], []
directory_1= r'C:\Users\.....\angle-model\MP_DATA'
direc=[]

for root, subdirectories, filenames in (sorted(os.walk(directory_1))):
    subdirectories=natsorted(subdirectories)
    for dirs in subdirectories:
        direc.append(dirs)

direc=np.array(direc)
for directory in direc:
    directory_2=(os.path.join(directory_1, directory))
for action in actions:
    window = []
    for root, subdirectories, filenames in (sorted(os.walk(directory_2))):
        filenames = natsorted(filenames)
        for filename in filenames:
            res=np.load(os.path.join(directory_2, filename))
            window.append(res)
    sequences.append(window)
    labels.append(label_map[action])
```

The above code is stuck within the same folder and doesnt move to the next folder. If I take a print of filenames, its repetitive.

```
['72.npy', '144.npy', '216.npy', '288.npy', '360.npy', '432.npy', '504.npy', '576.npy', '648.npy', '720.npy', '792.npy', '864.npy', '936.npy', '1008.npy', '1080.npy', '1152.npy', '1224.npy', '1296.npy', '1368.npy', '1440.npy', '1512.npy', '1584.npy', '1656.npy', '1728.npy', '1800.npy', '1872.npy', '1944.npy', '2016.npy', '2088.npy', '2160.npy', '2232.npy', '2304.npy', '2376.npy', '2448.npy', '2520.npy', '2592.npy', '2664.npy', '2736.npy', '2808.npy', '2880.npy', '2952.npy', '3024.npy', '3096.npy', '3168.npy', '3240.npy', '3312.npy', '3384.npy', '3456.npy', '3528.npy', '3600.npy', '3672.npy', '3744.npy', '3816.npy', '3888.npy', '3960.npy', '4032.npy', '4104.npy', '4176.npy', '4248.npy', '4320.npy', '4392.npy', '4464.npy', '4536.npy', '4608.npy', '4680.npy', '4752.npy', '4824.npy', '4896.npy', '4968.npy', '5040.npy', '5112.npy', '5184.npy', '5256.npy', '5328.npy', '5400.npy', '5472.npy', '5544.npy', '5616.npy', '5688.npy', '5760.npy', '5832.npy', '5904.npy', '5976.npy', '6048.npy', '6120.npy', '6192.npy', '6264.npy', '6336.npy', '6408.npy', '6480.npy', '6552.npy', '6624.npy', '6696.npy', '6768.npy', '6840.npy', '6912.npy', '6984.npy', '7056.npy', '7128.npy', '7200.npy', '7272.npy', '7344.npy', '7416.npy', '7488.npy', '7560.npy', '7632.npy', '7704.npy', '7776.npy', '7848.npy', '7920.npy', '7992.npy', '8064.npy', '8136.npy', '8208.npy', '8280.npy', '8352.npy', '8424.npy', '8496.npy', '8568.npy', '8640.npy', '8712.npy', '8784.npy', '8856.npy', '8928.npy', '9000.npy', '9072.npy', '9144.npy', '9216.npy', '9288.npy', '9360.npy', '9432.npy', '9504.npy', '9576.npy', '9648.npy', '9720.npy', '9792.npy', '9864.npy', '9936.npy', '10008.npy', '10080.npy', '10152.npy', '10224.npy', '10296.npy', '10368.npy', '10440.npy', '10512.npy', '10584.npy', '10656.npy', '10728.npy', '10800.npy', '10872.npy', '10944.npy', '11016.npy', '11088.npy', '11160.npy', '11232.npy', '11304.npy', '11376.npy', '11448.npy', '11520.npy', '11592.npy', '11664.npy', '11736.npy', '11808.npy', '11880.npy', '11952.npy', '12024.npy', '12096.npy', '12168.npy', '12240.npy', '12312.npy', '12384.npy', '12456.npy', '12528.npy', '12600.npy', '12672.npy', '12744.npy', '12816.npy', '12888.npy', '12960.npy', '13032.npy', '13104.npy', '13176.npy', '13248.npy', '13320.npy', '13392.npy', '13464.npy', '13536.npy', '13608.npy', '13680.npy', '13752.npy', '13824.npy', '13896.npy', '13968.npy', '14040.npy', '14112.npy', '14184.npy', '14256.npy', '14328.npy', '14400.npy', '14472.npy', '14544.npy', '14616.npy', '14688.npy', '14760.npy', '14832.npy', '14904.npy', '14976.npy', '15048.npy', '15120.npy', '15192.npy', '15264.npy', '15336.npy', '15408.npy', '15480.npy', '15552.npy', '15624.npy', '15696.npy', '15768.npy', '15840.npy', '15912.npy', '15984.npy', '16056.npy', '16128.npy', '16200.npy', '16272.npy', '16344.npy', '16416.npy', '16488.npy', '16560.npy', '16632.npy', '16704.npy', '16776.npy', '16848.npy', '16920.npy', '16992.npy', '17064.npy', '17136.npy', '17208.npy', '17280.npy', '17352.npy', '17424.npy', '17496.npy', '17568.npy']
.
.
.
.
['72.npy', '144.npy', '216.npy', '288.npy', '360.npy', '432.npy', '504.npy', '576.npy', '648.npy', '720.npy', '792.npy', '864.npy', '936.npy', '1008.npy', '1080.npy', '1152.npy', '1224.npy', '1296.npy', '1368.npy', '1440.npy', '1512.npy', '1584.npy', '1656.npy', '1728.npy', '1800.npy', '1872.npy', '1944.npy', '2016.npy', '2088.npy', '2160.npy', '2232.npy', '2304.npy', '2376.npy', '2448.npy', '2520.npy', '2592.npy', '2664.npy', '2736.npy', '2808.npy', '2880.npy', '2952.npy', '3024.npy', '3096.npy', '3168.npy', '3240.npy', '3312.npy', '3384.npy', '3456.npy', '3528.npy', '3600.npy', '3672.npy', '3744.npy', '3816.npy', '3888.npy', '3960.npy', '4032.npy', '4104.npy', '4176.npy', '4248.npy', '4320.npy', '4392.npy', '4464.npy', '4536.npy', '4608.npy', '4680.npy', '4752.npy', '4824.npy', '4896.npy', '4968.npy', '5040.npy', '5112.npy', '5184.npy', '5256.npy', '5328.npy', '5400.npy', '5472.npy', '5544.npy', '5616.npy', '5688.npy', '5760.npy', '5832.npy', '5904.npy', '5976.npy', '6048.npy', '6120.npy', '6192.npy', '6264.npy', '6336.npy', '6408.npy', '6480.npy', '6552.npy', '6624.npy', '6696.npy', '6768.npy', '6840.npy', '6912.npy', '6984.npy', '7056.npy', '7128.npy', '7200.npy', '7272.npy', '7344.npy', '7416.npy', '7488.npy', '7560.npy', '7632.npy', '7704.npy', '7776.npy', '7848.npy', '7920.npy', '7992.npy', '8064.npy', '8136.npy', '8208.npy', '8280.npy', '8352.npy', '8424.npy', '8496.npy', '8568.npy', '8640.npy', '8712.npy', '8784.npy', '8856.npy', '8928.npy', '9000.npy', '9072.npy', '9144.npy', '9216.npy', '9288.npy', '9360.npy', '9432.npy', '9504.npy', '9576.npy', '9648.npy', '9720.npy', '9792.npy', '9864.npy', '9936.npy', '10008.npy', '10080.npy', '10152.npy', '10224.npy', '10296.npy', '10368.npy', '10440.npy', '10512.npy', '10584.npy', '10656.npy', '10728.npy', '10800.npy', '10872.npy', '10944.npy', '11016.npy', '11088.npy', '11160.npy', '11232.npy', '11304.npy', '11376.npy', '11448.npy', '11520.npy', '11592.npy', '11664.npy', '11736.npy', '11808.npy', '11880.npy', '11952.npy', '12024.npy', '12096.npy', '12168.npy', '12240.npy', '12312.npy', '12384.npy', '12456.npy', '12528.npy', '12600.npy', '12672.npy', '12744.npy', '12816.npy', '12888.npy', '12960.npy', '13032.npy', '13104.npy', '13176.npy', '13248.npy', '13320.npy', '13392.npy', '13464.npy', '13536.npy', '13608.npy', '13680.npy', '13752.npy', '13824.npy', '13896.npy', '13968.npy', '14040.npy', '14112.npy', '14184.npy', '14256.npy', '14328.npy', '14400.npy', '14472.npy', '14544.npy', '14616.npy', '14688.npy', '14760.npy', '14832.npy', '14904.npy', '14976.npy', '15048.npy', '15120.npy', '15192.npy', '15264.npy', '15336.npy', '15408.npy', '15480.npy', '15552.npy', '15624.npy', '15696.npy', '15768.npy', '15840.npy', '15912.npy', '15984.npy', '16056.npy', '16128.npy', '16200.npy', '16272.npy', '16344.npy', '16416.npy', '16488.npy', '16560.npy', '16632.npy', '16704.npy', '16776.npy', '16848.npy', '16920.npy', '16992.npy', '17064.npy', '17136.npy', '17208.npy', '17280.npy', '17352.npy', '17424.npy', '17496.npy', '17568.npy']
```

Action in actions are simply the label names, which is used to create the folders within the MP_Data directory. So here is the code for actions

```
DATA_PATH = os.path.join('MP_DATA')

actions=np.array(['r0', 'r5', 'r10', 'r15', 'r20', 'r25', 'r30', 'r35', 'r40', 'r45', 'r50', 'r55', 'r60', 'r65', 'r70', 'r75', 'r80', 'r85', 'r90', 'r95', 'r100', 'r105', 'r110', 'r115', 'r120', 'r125', 'r130', 'r135', 'r140', 'r145', 'r150', 'r155', 'r160', 'r165', 'r170', 'r175', 'r180', 'r185', 'r190', 'r195', 'r200', 'r205', 'r210', 'r215', 'r220', 'r225', 'r230', 'r235', 'r240', 'r245', 'r250', 'r255', 'r260', 'r265', 'r270', 'r275', 'r280', 'r285', 'r290', 'r295', 'r300', 'r305', 'r310', 'r315', 'r320', 'r325', 'r330', 'r335', 'r340', 'r345', 'r350', 'r355'])
print(len(actions))

for action in actions: 
    try: 
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Your nesting is wrong – that `for action` loop should likely be nested within the `for directory` loop.

Comment: I think thats all right. The only problem is in looping through the directory.

Comment: I do think the problem here is that you only use the last `directory_2` value.

Comment: You successfully loop through each `directory in direc`, creating the corresponding `directory_2` *and doing nothing else*. Then you loop *once* `for action in actions:`, using the *last* value of `directory_2`. Voting to close as a typo, since you evidently already do know how nesting `for` loops works. Next time, please try to debug the code in more detail. For example, checking the value of `action` would reveal the error, since it wouldn't start over and iterate a second time through `actions`. You should also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: "The above code is stuck within the same folder and doesnt move to the next folder." What you are seeing is that `os.walk(directory_2)` *only finds one folder*, and `for action in actions:` repeats that loop, so that you see that one folder multiple times.

Comment: That said, the code seems much more complex than the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could simplify (aside from `actions`, which you don't show us) to something like

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

root = "/tmp/mp_data"

# Map labels (subdirectories of root) to data
data_per_label = defaultdict(list)

# Get all top-level directories within `root`
label_dirs = [
    name for name in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, name))
]
print(f"{label_dirs=}")

# Loop over each label directory
for label in label_dirs:
    label_dir = os.path.join(root, label)
    # Loop over each filename in the label directory
    for filename in os.listdir(label_dir):
        # Take care to only look at .npy files
        if filename.endswith(".npy"):
            filepath = os.path.join(label_dir, filename)
            print(f"{label=} {filename=} {filepath=}")
            data = filename  # replace with np.load(filename)
            data_per_label[label].append(data)

print(data_per_label)
```

Given a tree like

```
/tmp/mp_data
├── r1
│   └── a.npy
├── r2
│   └── b.npy
└── r3
    └── c.npy
```

this prints out

```
label_dirs=['r1', 'r3', 'r2']
label='r1' filename='a.npy' filepath='/tmp/mp_data/r1/a.npy'
label='r3' filename='c.npy' filepath='/tmp/mp_data/r3/c.npy'
label='r2' filename='b.npy' filepath='/tmp/mp_data/r2/b.npy'
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'r1': ['/tmp/mp_data/r1/a.npy'], 'r3': ['/tmp/mp_data/r3/c.npy'], 'r2': ['/tmp/mp_data/r2/b.npy']})
```

Comment: You see, I am not worried about the order of numpy files. I am more concerned with reading the folders in order r1,r2,r3 rather than r1,r3,r2. Also it throws up a syntax error. Not sure where the error is ```File "<fstring>", line 1
    (label_dirs=)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: You can get rid of that print statement (or the `=` in the f-string). You're using an older version of Python that doesn't support `=` in f-strings.

Comment: How about we contact on codementor. Already messaged you there

Comment: This is the result I get ```['r0', 'r10', 'r100', 'r105', 'r110', 'r115', 'r120', 'r125', 'r130', 'r135', 'r140', 'r145', 'r15', 'r150', 'r155', 'r160', 'r165', 'r170', 'r175', 'r180', 'r185', 'r190', 'r195', 'r20', 'r200', 'r205', 'r210', 'r215', 'r220', 'r225', 'r230', 'r235', 'r240', 'r245', 'r25', 'r250', 'r255', 'r260', 'r265', 'r270', 'r275', 'r280', 'r285', 'r290', 'r295', 'r30', 'r300', 'r305', 'r310', 'r315', 'r320', 'r325', 'r330', 'r335', 'r340', 'r345', 'r35', 'r350', 'r355', 'r40', 'r45', 'r5', 'r50', 'r55', 'r60', 'r65', 'r70', 'r75', 'r80', 'r85', 'r90', 'r95']```

Comment: Well, you already have that natsorted() function - wrap that around the label_dirs assignment...

Answer (score 2):

This is much simpler than you're making it.

> have a directory that has 72 folders, and within each folder are 245 numpy files. The directory is called MP_Data. I would like to read all the 245 numpy files within each folder in any order. However, the loop through the folders should be in numerical order.

From the documentation for os.walk:

> When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again.

So, we use that feature to make the `os.walk` visit all the subdirectories and files in the correct order, and we read the files as we encounter them. We should only need to `os.walk` *once*. Thus:

```py
window = []
for current, subdirectories, filenames in sorted(os.walk(directory_1)):
    subdirectories[:] = natsorted(subdirectories)
    for filename in filenames:
        window.append(np.load(os.path.join(current, filename)))
```

Having read each file once and built a list of the data, we can then just clone that data for each `action in actions`:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
sequences = [deepcopy(window) for action in actions]
labels = [label_map[action] for action in actions]
```

Assuming that you actually need separate data for each action, that is. That would depend on the rest of your program.

Comment: This still doesnt work. Let me explain. So even though you are using natsort to sort the subdirectories in the numerical order, the folders are still accessed using the os.walk default order. So the code ```for filename in filenames``` accesses folders in the order r0,r10,r100 instead of accessing r0,r5,r10,r15...  And hence this does not matches up with the label names being stored for the numpy files using ```for action in actions``` code. I hope now you see why this is not a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `action` loop inside the `directory` loop. If you don't, the `action` loop uses only the last directory of the `directory` loop.